# An special application about Jensen formula

Tags: complex-analysis

Let:$f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be entire non-constant, and let us set:

$T(r)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}log_+|f(re^{i\phi})|d\phi$,
here $\log_+{s}=max(logs,0)$, show that:

$T(r)\rightarrow\infty$ as $r\rightarrow\infty$

I have two tries:
1.Use Jensen formula, however, the trunction to logarithm makes it be scarcely possible
2. Use Laurent series, take T(r) to be $T(r)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\log_+|f(re^{i\phi})|^2d\phi$, this also false.

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One needs to use the Poisson-Jensen formula (Jensen formula is for $w=0$):

$\log |f(w)|- \sum_{|a_m|<R}\log |\frac{R(w-a_m)}{R^2-\bar a_m w}|=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\log |f(Re^{i\theta})|\frac{R^2-|w|^2}{|R-w|^2}d\theta, |w| <R$ and as usual $a_m$ are the zeroes of $f$ counted with multiplicity (where we assume wlog $w \ne a_1,..,a_m,..$ otherwise we need obvious modifications).

Poisson Jensen implies that (as we subtract negative terms on LHS):

$\log |f(w)| \le \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\log |f(Re^{i\theta})|\frac{R^2-|w|^2}{|R-w|^2}d\theta \le \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\log_+ |f(Re^{i\theta})|\frac{R^2-|w|^2}{|R-w|^2}d\theta$

Since $\frac{R^2-|w|^2}{|R-w|^2} \le \frac{R+|w|}{R-|w|}$ we get that (using crucially the fact that $\log_+ \ge 0$ here):

$\log |f(w)| \le \frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{R+|w|}{R-|w|}\int_0^{2\pi}\log_+ |f(Re^{i\theta})|d\theta=\frac{R+|w|}{R-|w|}T(R)$

Letting $M_f(r)=\max_{|z|=r}|f(w)|$ and appying the above with $r=R/2$ we get that:

$\log M_f(R/2) \le 3T(R)$ and now by Liouville $\log M_f(R/2) \to \infty, R \to \infty$ so we are done!

Note that if $f=e^g$ (in other words if $f$ has no zeroes), then $\int_0^{2\pi}\log |f(Re^{i\theta})|d\theta=2\pi \log |f(0)|$ so we do need $\log_+$ to ensure that the integrals go to infinity; more generally $\int_0^{2\pi}\log |f(Re^{i\theta})|d\theta$ counts the number of zeroes, while $\int_0^{2\pi}\log_+ |f(Re^{i\theta})|d\theta$ measures the growth rate of the maximum modulus of $f$ as we saw above

(the opposite inequality $T(R)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\log_+ |f(Re^{i\theta})|d\theta \le \log M_f(R)$ being trivial)

Comment: I know now! The Poisson Jensen formula avoid considering if $f(0)=0$, thank you very much!

Comment: Happy to be of help